# Cant save my own vs2015 c++ exe with ollydbg

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ollydbg

The save option is not visible when i open my own executables from visual studio 2015 with ollydbg.They are console programs written in c++.Is this normal?

Comment: What are you trying to save? The exe?

Comment: Yes.  Thats what i tried to do

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save the modifications you've made to the executable in Ollydbg, there is a way to do that. Press right mouse button. Choose "Edit" -> "Copy to executable". In the new window, press right mouse button and choose "Save file".